# RODBC Connection Failed Cant Find Server

Tags: r, odbc, rodbc

I am attempting to connect my local SQL server/database to Power BI through R using odbc.

I have been looking around online at many threads to try to find a solution. Other people have had my issue, but the solutions they were provided are not working for me. I'm sure this is simple, I just can't get it.

```r
ch <- odbcDriverConnect(
  "Driver={SQL Server};Server=localhost;Database=deliverydashboard;Trusted_Connection=TRUE"
)
```

These are the error messages I receive:

```
1: In odbcDriverConnect("Driver={SQL Server};Server=localhost;Database=deliverydashboard;Trusted_Connection=TRUE") :
  [RODBC] ERROR: state 08001, code 17, message [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]SQL Server does not exist or access denied.

2: In odbcDriverConnect("Driver={SQL Server};Server=localhost;Database=deliverydashboard;Trusted_Connection=TRUE") :
  [RODBC] ERROR: state 01000, code 2, message [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]ConnectionOpen (Connect()).

3: In odbcDriverConnect("Driver={SQL Server};Server=localhost;Database=deliverydashboard;Trusted_Connection=TRUE") :
  ODBC connection failed

Error in sqlQuery(ch, "DROP TABLE deliveryexpensebackend") : 
  first argument is not an open RODBC channel
Execution halted
```

Comment: My windows defaults to ipv6 (`::1`) for localhost, try `...;Server=127.0.0.1;...`.

Comment: I removed the tags [tag:mysql] (different DBMS) and [tag:sql] (you are not asking about SQL code, just the connection issues). Correct me if I removed them hastily.

Comment: Yes, sorry I should have included that I've tried using 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost. It generates the same error messages.